# author-date citation problem: how to print out title or author

Tags: xml, citations, csl

I've ran into a problem while creating a CSL style. For in-text citations I have to create an author-date element with the following conditions:

- when there're 1-3 authors, show [Author 1, Author 2, Author 3, Year]
- when there're more than 3 authors, show [Title, Year]

I've tried suppress-max but none helped it me in figuring out

Examples:
1 author
[Doe, 2022]

2 authors
[Doe, Gogh, 2022]

3 authors
[Doe, Gogh, Johnson, 2022]

4 authors
[Climate change impacts, 2022]

`<macro name="author_short"> <names variable="author"> <name form="short" name-as-sort-order="all" sort-separator=" " delimiter=", " delimiter-precedes-last="always"/> <substitute> <text variable="title"/> </substitute> </names> </macro>`

Comment: "suppress-max" btw. is nothing that exists or has ever existed in CSL. While the specifications (https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html ) are not always easy to read to figure out how to do something, if searching within the spec for a command returns empty, it definitely doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to use the et al settings and then set the term for et al to an empty string.
So change your `author-short` macro to

```
<macro name="author_short">
  <names variable="author">
    <name et-al-min="4" et-al-use-first="1" form="short" name-as-sort-order="all" sort-separator=" " delimiter=", " delimiter-precedes-last="always"/>
    <substitute> 
      <text variable="title"/> 
    </substitute> 
  </names>
</macro>
```

(If you want to submit the style to the CSL repository, it's recommended to set et al on `<citation>` and not in the author macro)

And then define an empty et al term in a [locale section](https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#locale) at the beginning of the style, right below the `:

```
<locale>
  <terms>
    <term name="et-al"></term>
  </term>
</locale>
```

Edit:
If you do need the et-al term otherwise, you can [define and call](https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#et-al) the term for `and others` like so:

```
    <locale>
      <terms>
        <term name="and others"></term>
      </term>
    </locale>
```

and then in the macro use

```
<macro name="author_short">
  <names variable="author">
    <name et-al-min="4" et-al-use-first="1" form="short" name-as-sort-order="all" sort-separator=" " delimiter=", " delimiter-precedes-last="always"/>
  <et-al term="and others"/>
    <substitute> 
      <text variable="title"/> 
    </substitute> 
  </names>
</macro>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, how could I do this without an empty et-al term. The thing is it's used for bibliography, e.g.:
1. Author N. [et al.]. Title. Year. Wouldn't an empty et-al term result in losing the info about authors if there're plenty of them in the bibliographical block at the end of a document?

Comment: @AlexanderPlesovskikh -- see edited answer above